# Delete entire blank columns

Tags: excel, vba

Need to delete blank columns in a worksheet.  I need the whole column delete sho it move the imported columns with text into in to be at the start of the sheet.  The placement of the columns with text in them will change weekly so I need something that can delete full columns until the last text column.  Code I was trying is listed below.

[image]

```
Sub Delete_Columns
 C = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
   Do Until C = 0
   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(C)) = 0 Then
   Columns(C).Delete
   End If
   C = C - 1
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working for you?

Comment: @BigBen I have added a picture as to where the text stats.  As you can tell it starts in column TN.  One this page I need it to start in the A column

Comment: So what happens or doesn't happen when you use the above code?

Comment: @BigBen When I run the code column A to TM are blank, sorry I thought I made that clear.  I need the text to start in Column A

Comment: The provided code works for me with text in column TN and blanks in columns A to TM. After running, the text is shifted to column A. How exactly is the provided code not working for you?

Comment: @BigBen I was running the code as part of the code that imports the text onto this sheet.  I tried it just along and it works.

Comment: Ok so what happens when it *doesn't* work?

Comment: When it doesn't work it puts the text starting in column TN

Comment: My guess is that `ActiveSheet` is not the one you think it is then.

Comment: @BigBen no, it is.  I think the problem is with the large code inside that module that's screwing it up somehow.  When you mentioned that you got it to work, I figured that it might be the large code, so I just put it in it's own module and all good now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Delete Blank Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteBlankColumns()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim dcrg As Range
    Dim crg As Range
    
    For Each crg In rg.Columns
        If Application.CountBlank(crg) = rCount Then
            If dcrg Is Nothing Then
                Set dcrg = crg
            Else
                Set dcrg = Union(dcrg, crg)
            End If
        End If
    Next crg
    If dcrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
       
    dcrg.EntireColumn.Delete
    
End Sub
```